# HTML grid creates annoying margin on the right side of my webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css, margin

I've developed [this](https://joogps.github.io/Grid-Template/) website to test an idea I had in my mind. The problem is that the grid design creates a very annoying margin on the right side of the page that isn't part of any HTML tag, which glitches the zooming in/out effect.

I've already tried to set all of the margins and paddings to 0px, like this:

```
html, body, div {
  margin: 0px
  padding: 0px;
}
```

Changing the width of those elements doensn't work either.

[(link to the GitHub repo that holds the page)](https://github.com/joogps/Grid-Template)

```js
let loremipsum = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed eget libero vel arcu pharetra finibus. Morbi sem dui, mollis eget sollicitudin ac, tincidunt in ligula. Nulla finibus lorem vitae nisi blandit, nec bibendum nibh tempor. Pellentesque vestibulum, felis ac vehicula venenatis, nisl leo sollicitudin enim, eu porttitor augue ex eget lorem. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Quisque gravida mollis elit. Pellentesque convallis nisi non lectus porttitor, non convallis ligula posuere. Donec eu metus vel risus finibus faucibus.".split(" ");
var container = $(".grid-container");
for (var i = 0; i < loremipsum.length; i++) {
  var hue = Math.round(Math.random() * 360 / 45) * 45;
  var item = $("<div></div>").css("background-image", "linear-gradient(to right, hsl(" + hue + ", 100%, 50%), hsl(" + hue + ", 100%, 35%))").addClass("grid-item");
  var contents = $("<div></div>").text(loremipsum[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + loremipsum[i].substr(1, loremipsum[i].length)).addClass("grid-contents");
  item.append(contents);
  container.append(item);
}
$(".grid-item").each(function(i, obj) {
  $(this).click(function() {
    upperleft($(this));
    if ($(this).data("grown") == true)
      shrink($(this));
    else
      grow($(this));
  });
});

function upperleft(elm) {
  elm.css({
    "top": -elm.position().top - elm.height() + elm.height() / 1.025 + $(window).scrollTop() + "px",
    "left": -elm.position().left - elm.width() + elm.width() / 1.025 + "px"
  });
}

function grow(elm) {
  elm.css({
    "width": window.outerWidth + "px",
    "height": window.outerHeight + "px",
    "z-index": "1",
    "border-radius": "0px"
  }).data("grown", true);
  $("body").attr({
    "scroll": "no",
    "style": "overflow: hidden"
  });
}

function shrink(elm) {
  elm.css({
    "width": "100%",
    "height": "300px",
    "z-index": "0",
    "border-radius": "30px"
  }).data("grown", false);
  $("body").attr({
    "scroll": "yes",
    "style": "overflow: scroll"
  });
}
```

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(250px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 25px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.grid-item {
  border-radius: 30px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  transform: scale(1);
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  transition: transform 0.25s, top 0.25s, left 0.25s, width 0.25s, height 0.25s, border-radius 0.25s;
}

.grid-item:hover {
  transform: scale(1.025);
}

.grid-contents {
  position: relative;
  top: 10%;
  left: 12%;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="grid-container"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

When the page is scrolled all the way to the right we can see that there is more whitespace there than on the left side.

[left side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9aqoR.png)
[right side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qUJd.png)

Comment: Ciao João - welcome to SO. It is best to add the code directly to your post (as I have done for you). The reason is that these links may not survive for long and then everyone looses out. In addition, if you don't do this your question will likely get downvoted and deleted or put on hold as insufficiently detailed. You can read more in the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: There is no _**very annoying margin on the right side of the page**_ can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: It looks like there is more white space in the right than in the left. And, if you take a look on Chrome DevTools, it is part of no element at all.

Comment: And you are referring to the **page** and not one of the grid blocks after it is resized back from "fullscreen"? Or is that a different problem?

Comment: That's a different problem. I hope they are tied together so I don't need to solve both... But, by now, I want to solve the margin one.

Comment: I'm using Safari (I'll check chrome in a minute), and I see a user agent 8px margin applied on all side - not just the right.

Comment: That margin does affect the page, but, even if you remove it, there is still a tiny spot in the right that seems to come from nowhere.

Comment: As I suspected, in Chrome I see exactly the same thing - user agent margin of 8px all the way around.

Comment: I do not see that "tiny spot in the right" after I edited the post. to remove the margins from body and html in either chrome or safari. Turn all your browser extensions off and look again.

Comment: max-width:100%; should be used on containing elements. It will keep everything inside the browser with no horizontal scroll bar! ~~ Confirmed: there is extra space on right causing a scroll bar.

Comment: Thanks, Nerdi.org! But, as many other solutions, that one didn't fix what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

I wrapped it into a div container with overflow hidden and a width of 100% to stop the page expansion

```js
let loremipsum = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed eget libero vel arcu pharetra finibus. Morbi sem dui, mollis eget sollicitudin ac, tincidunt in ligula. Nulla finibus lorem vitae nisi blandit, nec bibendum nibh tempor. Pellentesque vestibulum, felis ac vehicula venenatis, nisl leo sollicitudin enim, eu porttitor augue ex eget lorem. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Quisque gravida mollis elit. Pellentesque convallis nisi non lectus porttitor, non convallis ligula posuere. Donec eu metus vel risus finibus faucibus.".split(" ");
var container = $(".grid-container");
for (var i = 0; i < loremipsum.length; i++) {
  var hue = Math.round(Math.random() * 360 / 45) * 45;
  var item = $("<div></div>").css("background-image", "linear-gradient(to right, hsl(" + hue + ", 100%, 50%), hsl(" + hue + ", 100%, 35%))").addClass("grid-item");
  var contents = $("<div></div>").text(loremipsum[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + loremipsum[i].substr(1, loremipsum[i].length)).addClass("grid-contents");
  item.append(contents);
  container.append(item);
}
$(".grid-item").each(function(i, obj) {
  $(this).click(function() {
    upperleft($(this));
    if ($(this).data("grown") == true)
      shrink($(this));
    else
      grow($(this));
  });
});

function upperleft(elm) {
  elm.css({
    "top": -elm.position().top - elm.height() + elm.height() / 1.025 + $(window).scrollTop() + "px",
    "left": -elm.position().left - elm.width() + elm.width() / 1.025 + "px"
  });
}

function grow(elm) {
  elm.css({
    "width": window.outerWidth + "px",
    "height": window.outerHeight + "px",
    "z-index": "1",
    "border-radius": "0px"
  }).data("grown", true);
  $("body").attr({
    "scroll": "no",
    "style": "overflow: hidden"
  });
}

function shrink(elm) {
  elm.css({
    "width": "100%",
    "height": "300px",
    "z-index": "0",
    "border-radius": "30px"
  }).data("grown", false);
  $("body").attr({
    "scroll": "yes",
    "style": "overflow: scroll"
  });
}
```

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.containsAll{
width:100%;
overflow:hidden;
}
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(250px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 25px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.grid-item {
  border-radius: 30px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  transform: scale(1);
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  transition: transform 0.25s, top 0.25s, left 0.25s, width 0.25s, height 0.25s, border-radius 0.25s;
}

.grid-item:hover {
  transform: scale(1.025);
}

.grid-contents {
  position: relative;
  top: 10%;
  left: 12%;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="containsAll">
  <div class="grid-container"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I've already tried that, but, apparently, the bug I'm trying to fix still happens, as you can see by expanding the last item of each row.

Comment: @JoãoGabriel  are you talking about the page expanding on hover when the cell gets larger?

Comment: No, when you click the cell!

Comment: Ok i see it thats in the javascript let me take a look

Comment: There still are some other bugs for me to fix (so don't worry if you find them), but that one is by far the most important!